# The correct way to delete all images files in a folder older than 2 days in PHP

Tags: php

I want to delete all images those are older than 2 days or any number of days I want to add. I will add that file in cron job which will work on X no of days. I have used the below code for preforming this action.

```
    <?php
    $folderName='uploads';
    if (file_exists($folderName)) {
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folderName) as $fileInfo) {
            if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
            continue;
            }
            if ($fileInfo->isFile() && time() - $fileInfo->getCTime() >= 2*24*60*60) {
                unlink($fileInfo->getRealPath());
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This code is not providing any error but Its not deleting images from the folder. I have tried many other codes from Internet but no success. So I need this small help.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging to see what part of that code isn't behaving as you expect?  Throw in some `echo` statements and see which ones run.  Then you'll have it narrowed down to a specific problem instead of "my code doesn't work"

Comment: Have you verified the user running the script has permissions to delete the files? As a suggestion I think your delete condition would be easier to understand like this: `$fileInfo->getCTime() <= time() - (60 * 60 * 48)`

Comment: Any reason to use getCTime instead of getMTime?

Comment: Your code works exactly as expected for me. Try using a fully qualified location for `$folderName` instead of just a name by itself. Otherwise your code will depend on the location it is being run from.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/files/';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($path . $file);
        //24 hours in a day * 3600 seconds per hour
        if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 24*3600)
        {
           unlink($path . $file);
        }

    }

    closedir($handle); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Its giving below error

Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for uploads100_925_sterling_silver_dream_catcher_holder_finger_ring_for_women_at_shoppysanta__buy_now_at_upto_90_off_5226148900.png in C:\xampp\htdocs\clean-site\delete-images.php on line 6

Warning: unlink(uploads100_925_sterling_silver_dream_catcher_holder_finger_ring_for_women_at_shoppysanta__buy_now_at_upto_90_off_5226148900.png): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\clean-site\delete-images.php on line 10

Comment: if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}  use the if condition to check the file exist or not

Answer (score 0):

You can call shell command from php like this,

`find /data/haoqi_backup/db_code/db* -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;`